# AJAX and jQuery just do not get along together

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a very simple question that i hope someone would actually have an answer to it.

if jQuery events are being bind to the already existing selectors in the HTML document, how can i refresh jQuery to include the new generated HTML code with AJAX?. (without using `.delegate()` since it has been deprecated)

even trying to bind the events to a container that doesn't change during the ajax request like such: `$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){// do something});` didn't work out

for more reference on this issue (jQuery not binding to the HTML generated by AJAX).. please [check my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298262/jquery-in-external-javascript-file-not-being-loaded)

Comment: What about `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`

Comment: question updated, @Musa

Comment: `.on()` is the way to go, If it didn't work you did something wrong. Post your **actual** code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `on` instead of `delegate` (see jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). For instance, if you want to trigger an action on every `div` inside `#RootElement`:

```
$("#RootElement").on("click", "div", function(event){
    console.log("Div content: " + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: can you please explain this in more details

Comment: it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) that this event `DOMSubtreeModified` has been deprecated

Comment: thank you @nicolas-cami i am researching this problem on the internet and it seems like linking `on()` to `$('#RootElement')` is the only solution. i need to go and check my code again because even by doing this the event still not binding. thanks again

Comment: Maybe you can edit your post and show us the involved HTML and javascript code.

Comment: thank you for your consideration, my HTML code is mostly generated using mustache templates an AJAX. i was hopping that there is a general jQuery function that will cause the events to rebind or something. really appreciate your answer thanks again